# Netty 4 difference between channel.close() vs channel.disconnect()

Tags: netty

I am writing a netty HTTP client with pooled connection, now i added `pipeline.addLast("Timeout", new ReadTimeoutHandler(readTimeout));` while building the channel pipeline.

So in `ReadTimeoutException` i want to just close this connection, without disturbing any other connection in the pool, Now my doubt is shall i call channel.close() and channel.disconnect(), or only channel.close() will be fine enough.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14130575/116639