# Is there any difference betweent ctx.disconnect() and ctx.close() in netty? What are those two function application scenarios?

Tags: tcp, netty

```
public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
    super.userEventTriggered(ctx, evt);
    if (evt instanceof IdleStateEvent) {
        IdleStateEvent event = (IdleStateEvent) evt;
        if (event.state().equals(IdleState.READER_IDLE)) {
            System.out.println("READER_IDLE");
            ctx.disconnect();
            ctx.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need invoke ctx.disconnect() before ctx.close()?

Comment: What does it say in the Javadoc?

Comment: You can find your answer over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128910/netty-calling-channel-disconnect-actually-closes-the-channel/14130575#14130575